# When using Facelets 404 error page, Websphere throws FileNotFoundException instead of dispatching to 404 error page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets, custom-error-pages, websphere-liberty

I am trying to define a Facelets page as a custom 404 error-page in my web.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
...
 <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
<error-page>
      <error-code>404</error-code>
      <location>/pageNotFound.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
...
</web-app>
```

Server.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server description="new server">

    <!-- Enable features -->

<featureManager>
        <feature>jsp-2.2</feature> 
            <feature>ejbLite-3.1</feature> 
                <feature>jpa-2.0</feature> 
                <feature>jsf-2.0</feature> 
                <feature>cdi-1.0</feature> 
                <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature> 
                <feature>jaxws-2.2</feature> 
                <feature>jaxrs-1.1</feature> 
        </featureManager> 


    <httpEndpoint host="*" httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443" id="defaultHttpEndpoint"/> 

<applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean"/> 
    ...

</server>
```

Now if I deploy to Websphere liberty profile 8.5.5.4 and go to [app_root]/abc for example, I don't see my custom error-page. Instead I see the server default error page:

```
Error Message: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /abc
Error Code: 404
Target Servlet: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor
Error Stack: 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /abc 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:528) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1101) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4797) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:297) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:981) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:262) 
     at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:938) 
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) 
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) 
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This worked on my previous project where we used a WildFly 8.2.0.final server. When I try this with a JSP instead of Facelets page, then it does work.

Is it possible to use a Facelets page as custom error-page in Websphere liberty profile 8.5.5.4? Do I need more configuration on Websphere? Or I am just missing something here?

Comment: So you request *abc* without an extension? What happens when you try it with an extension?

Comment: When I go to abc.xhtml it is dispatched to the correct page. But then I also see an error in my logs: `Exception thrown by application class 'org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.context.flash.FlashImpl.isKeepMessages:392'
java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Comment: Looks like your container and MyFaces distribution are buggy: The fact that the error page valve won't catch a bogus URL because it's lacking an extension points to a container bug; the MyFaces exception is obviously a bug in their implementation of the flashscope